# Parameter Sniffing vs VARIABLES vs Recompile vs OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN

Tags: sql-server-2008, execution-plan, cache

So we had a long running proc causing problems this morning (30 sec + run time).  We decided to check to see if parameter sniffing was to blame.  So, we rewrote the proc and set the incoming parameters to variables so as to defeat parameter sniffing.  A tried/true approach.  Bam, query time improved (less than 1 sec).  When looking at the query plan the improvements were found in an index the original wasn't using.

Just to verify that we didn't get a false positive we did a dbcc freeproccache on the original proc and reran to see if the improved results would be the same.  But, to our surprise the original proc still ran slow.  We tried again with a WITH RECOMPILE, still slow (we tried a recompile on the call to the proc and inside the proc it'self).  We even restarted the server (dev box obviously).

So, my question is this... how can parameter sniffing be to blame when we get the same slow query on an empty plan cache... there shouldn't be any parameters to snif???

Are we instead being affected by table stats not related to the plan cache.  And if so, why would setting the incoming parameters to variables help??

In further testing we also found that inserting the OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) on the internals of the proc **DID** get the expected improved plan.

So, some of you folks smarter than I, can you give some clues as to whats going on behind the scenes to produce this type of result?

*On another note, the slow plan also get's aborted early with reason `GoodEnoughPlanFound` while the fast plan has no early abort reason in the actual plan.*

In summary

- Creating variables out of incoming parameters (1 sec)
- with recompile (30+ sec)
- dbcc freeproccache (30+ sec)
- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UKNOWN) (1 sec)

**UPDATE:**

See slow execution plan here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmx2lrsea8q8mr6/plan_slow.xml

See fast execution plan here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b28x6a01w7dxsed/plan_fast.xml

*Note: table, schema, object names changed for security reasons.*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The query is

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SummaryTotal
FROM   PDetail WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  ClientID = @merchid
       AND PostedDate BETWEEN @datebegin AND @dateend
```

The table contains 103,129,000 rows.

The fast plan looks up by ClientId with a residual predicate on the date but needs to do 96 lookups to retrieve the `Amount`. The `<ParameterList>` section in the plan is as follows.

```
        <ParameterList>
          <ColumnReference Column="@dateend" 
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="'2013-02-01 23:59:00.000'" />
          <ColumnReference Column="@datebegin" 
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="'2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'" />
          <ColumnReference Column="@merchid" 
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="(78155)" />
        </ParameterList>
```

The slow plan looks up by date and has lookups to evaluate the residual predicate on ClientId and to retrieve the amount (Estimated 1 vs Actual 7,388,383). The `<ParameterList>` section is

```
        <ParameterList>
          <ColumnReference Column="@EndDate" 
                           ParameterCompiledValue="'2013-02-01 23:59:00.000'" 
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="'2013-02-01 23:59:00.000'" />
          <ColumnReference Column="@BeginDate" 
                           ParameterCompiledValue="'2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'"               
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="'2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'" />
          <ColumnReference Column="@ClientID" 
                           ParameterCompiledValue="(78155)" 
                           ParameterRuntimeValue="(78155)" />
        </ParameterList>
```

In this second case the `ParameterCompiledValue` is **not** empty. SQL Server successfully sniffed the values used in the query.

The book ["SQL Server 2005 Practical Troubleshooting"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321447743) has this to say about using local variables

> Using local variables to defeat parameter sniffing is a fairly common
> trick, but the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR)` hints
> ... are generally more elegant and slightly less risky solutions
>
> ---
>
> #### Note
>
> In SQL Server 2005, statement level compilation allows for compilation
> of an individual statement in a stored procedure to be deferred until
> just before the first execution of the query. By then the local
> variable's value would be known. Theoretically SQL Server could take
> advantage of this to sniff local variable values in the same way that
> it sniffs parameters. However because it was common to use local
> variables to defeat parameter sniffing in SQL Server 7.0 and SQL
> Server 2000+, sniffing of local variables was not enabled in SQL
> Server 2005. It may be enabled in a future SQL Server release though
> which is a good reason to use one of the other options outlined in
> this chapter if you have a choice.
>
> ---

From a quick test this end the behaviour described above is still the same in 2008 and 2012 and variables are not sniffed for deferred compile but only when an explicit `OPTION RECOMPILE` hint is used.

```
DECLARE @N INT = 0

CREATE TABLE #T ( I INT );

/*Reference to #T means this statement is subject to deferred compile*/
SELECT *
FROM   master..spt_values
WHERE  number = @N
       AND EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #T)

SELECT *
FROM   master..spt_values
WHERE  number = @N
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

DROP TABLE #T
```

**Despite deferred compile the variable is not sniffed and the estimated row count is inaccurate**

[image: Estimates vs Actual]

So I assume that the slow plan relates to a parameterised version of the query.

The `ParameterCompiledValue` is equal to `ParameterRuntimeValue` for all of the parameters so this is not typical parameter sniffing (where the plan was compiled for one set of values then run for another set of values).

The problem is that the plan that is compiled for the correct parameter values is inappropriate.

You are likely hitting the issue with ascending dates described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210613152827/https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029234641/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianjo/archive/2006/04/24/582227.aspx). For a table with 100 million rows you need to insert (or otherwise modify) 20 million before SQL Server will automatically update the statistics for you. It seems that last time they were updated zero rows matched the date range in the query but now 7 million do.

You could schedule more frequent statistics updates, consider trace flags `2389 - 90` or use `OPTIMIZE FOR UKNOWN` so it just falls back on guesses rather than being able to use the currently misleading statistics on the `datetime` column.

This might not be necessary in the next version of SQL Server (after 2012). A [related Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/316364/better-support-for-finding-ascending-indexes) contains the intriguing response

> **Posted by Microsoft on 8/28/2012 at 1:35 PM** 
> We've done a cardinality
> estimation enhancement for the next major release that essentially
> fixes this. Stay tuned for details once our previews come out.    Eric

This 2014 improvement is looked at by  Benjamin Nevarez towards the end of the article:

[A First Look at the New SQL Server Cardinality Estimator](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/12/t-sql-queries/a-first-look-at-the-new-sql-server-cardinality-estimator).

It appears the new cardinality estimator will fall back and use average density in this case rather than giving the 1 row estimate.

Some additional details about the 2014 cardinality estimator and ascending key problem here:

[New functionality in SQL Server 2014 – Part 2 – New Cardinality Estimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saponsqlserver/new-functionality-in-sql-server-2014-part-2-new-cardinality-estimation)

Answer (score 29):

> So, my question is this... how can parameter sniffing be to blame when
> we get the same slow query on an empty plan cache... there shouldn't
> be any parameters to sniff?

When SQL Server compiles a query containing parameter values, it [sniffs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mdegre/what-is-parameter-sniffing) the specific values of those parameters for cardinality (row count) estimation. In your case, the particular values of `@BeginDate`, `@EndDate` and `@ClientID` are used when choosing an execution plan. You can find more details about parameter sniffing [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/) and [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/pros-and-cons-parameter-sniffing). I am providing these background links because the question above makes me think the concept is imperfectly understood at present - there are always parameter values to sniff when a plan is compiled.

Anyway, that's all beside the point, because parameter sniffing is not the problem here as Martin Smith has pointed out. At the time the slow query was compiled, the statistics indicated there were no rows for the sniffed values of `@BeginDate` and `@EndDate`:

[image: Slow plan sniffed values]

The sniffed values are very recent, suggesting the [ascending key problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ianjo/ascending-keys-and-auto-quick-corrected-statistics) Martin mentions. Because the index seek on the dates is estimated to return just a single row, the optimizer chooses a plan that pushes the predicate on `ClientID` to the Key Lookup operator as a residual.

The single row estimate is also the reason the optimizer stops looking for better plans, returning a Good Enough Plan Found message. The estimated total cost of the slow plan with the single row estimate is just 0.013136 cost units, so there is no point trying to find anything better. Except, of course, the seek actually returns 7,388,383 rows rather than one, causing the same number of Key Lookups.

Statistics can be tricky to keep up-to-date and useful on large tables and partitioning introduces [challenges](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328093/statistics-are-saved-on-table-level-and-not-on-partition-level) of its own in that regard. I have not had particular success myself with trace flags 2389 and 2390, but you are welcome to test them. More recent builds of SQL Server (R2 SP1 and later) have [dynamic statistics updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saponsqlserver/changes-to-automatic-update-statistics-in-sql-server-traceflag-2371) available, but this [per-partition statistics updates](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303091945/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/468517/update-statistics-at-the-partition-level) are still not implemented. In the meantime, you might like to schedule a manual statistics update whenever you make significant changes to this table.

For this particular query, I would think about implementing the index suggested by the optimizer during compilation of the fast query plan:

```
/*
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve
the query cost by 98.8091%.

WARNING: This is only an estimate, and the Query Processor is making this 
recommendation based solely upon analysis of this specific query.
It has not considered the resulting index size, or its workload-wide impact,
including its impact on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE performance.
These factors should be taken into account before creating this index.
*/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index>]
ON [dbo].[PDetail] ([ClientID],[PostedDate])
INCLUDE ([Amount]);
```

The index should be partition-aligned, with an `ON PartitionSchemeName (PostedDate)` clause, but the point is that providing an obviously-best data access path will help the optimizer avoid poor plan choices, without resorting to `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` hints or old-fashioned workarounds like using local variables.

With the improved index, the Key Lookup to retrieve the `Amount` column will be eliminated, the query processor can still perform dynamic partition elimination, and use a seek to find the particular `ClientID` and date range.

Comment: Wish I could mark two answers as correct, but again, thanks for the additional info - very instructive.

Comment: It's been a couple years since I posted this... but I just wanted to let you know.  I still use the term "imperfectly understood" all the freaking time, and I always think of Paul White when I do.  Makes me chuckle every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem where a stored procedure became slow, and `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` and `RECOMPILE` query hints resolved the slowness and sped up the execution time. 
However, the following two methods did not affect the slowness of the stored procedure:
(i) Clearing the cache (ii) using WITH RECOMPILE. So, just like you said, it was not really parameter sniffing.

Trace flags 2389 and 2390 didn't help as well. Just updating the stats (`EXEC sp_updatestats`) did it for me.