# Using of OPTIMIZE FOR hints in a sql query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, hints, parameter-sniffing

As far as I know, the `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint helps to avoid parameter sniffing.

For such a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE param=@param1
```

We have two parameters `S1` with high selectivity and `S2` with low selectivity.

If we are using such a hint:

```
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR @param1=S1)
```

and then send `S2` to the stored procedure, we have still parameter sniffing.

Now I have a conceptual question:

How does the `OPTIMZE FOR` hint help us avoid parameter sniffing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OPTIMIZE FOR` is used for making a good plan for specific query. A classical example is a report to skewed data that is run very often with same parameters. In such a scenario, it could be useful to optimize the query for the most common parameter. This is a trade-off, as other queries with different parameter are going to get worse a plan.

If you are suffering from parameter sniffing, you could use `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`, `OPTION RECOMPILE` or local variables. None of these is a silver bullet, so bencmark the queries carefully. Make sure the issue really is parameter sniffing and not, say, out-of-date statistics.

A Microsoft [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/turgays/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds) discusses the issue with sample code, as [a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33698/4511) right here on dba.so.