# Force SQL Engine to prepare Non-Null plan only for a query that use variable

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have following two query approaches. The Approach 1 works in 20 seconds. The Approach 2 did not complete even after hours.

**Approach 1**

```
SELECT *,
        SUBSTRING(IDAndCode,CHARINDEX ('$', IDAndCode)+1, LEN(IDAndCode) - 2) AS ICDCode
From dbo.MyTable
WHERE F.Fact_Diagnosis_BK LIKE 'SKI-CE:'+'%' 
GO
```

**Approach 2**

```
DECLARE @DelimitingCharacter CHAR(1)
SET @DelimitingCharacter = '$'; 

SELECT *,
        SUBSTRING(IDAndCode,CHARINDEX (@DelimitingCharacter, IDAndCode)+1, LEN(IDAndCode) - 2) AS ICDCode
From dbo.MyTable
WHERE F.Fact_Diagnosis_BK LIKE 'SKI-CE:'+'%' 
GO
```

Note: The above two are simplified queries. The actual queries can be seen in the execution plan below.

**Execution Plans**

Actual Execution Plan – Approach 1
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJlcWTk3m

Estimated Plan - Approach 2:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJddO3en7

Note: The plan for Approach 2 uses `Nested Loop` join instead of `Hash Match` join

**Question**

I know that this can be fixed by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. If I understand it correctly, the slowness is happening since SQL Server is creating a plan to accommodate `NULL` possibility of the variable.

In my case, the variable will be `Non-Null` before the query is executed (guaranteed)

1. In SQL Server 2016, what are the possibilities to tell the SQL engine that the variable will be non-null and prepare a plan only for such condition, without using OPTION (RECOMPILE)?
2. Is the slowness called parameter sniffing? (There is no parameter here. It is a local variable in a stand alone query)

Note: I am trying to see options to get the query running faster without using RECOMPILE.

**References**:

1. [SQL Server Query: Fast with Literal but Slow with Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459425/sql-server-query-fast-with-literal-but-slow-with-variable)
2. [Improving query performance with OPTION (RECOMPILE), Constant Folding and avoiding Parameter Sniffing issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/)
3. [Parameter Sniffing vs VARIABLES vs Recompile vs OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33698/parameter-sniffing-vs-variables-vs-recompile-vs-optimize-for-unknown?rq=1)
4. [Local Variables vs. Parameterized Stored Procedures in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/local-variable-vs-stored-procedure/)

Comment: I am the only one using this dev server now. I am not running any other queries. Also, the behavior is repeated test after test.

Comment: I tried sp_executesql - but that didn't resolve the issue. It is still not completed even after long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the three ways that can fix the issue. More approaches are welcome.

**Solution 1**

Instead of a variable(@DelimitingCharacter), use a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #VariableHoldingTable (DelimitingCharacter CHAR(1) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #VariableHoldingTable
SELECT '<'
```

--And do a join

```
  INNER JOIN #VariableHoldingTable V
    ON 1 = 1
```

Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJpehe5hQ

**Solution 2**

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_DXID on #MultipleDiagnosisDXs(DXID)
```

Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1nKne9nX

**Solution 3**

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkRgalqnX

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #MultipleDiagnosisDXs (DXID INT Not null)
```

Notice `not null` here.After populating create index.

```
Create Clustered index IX_DXID on #MultipleDiagnosisDXs(DXID)
```

In query correct,

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DXID FROM #MultipleDiagnosisDXs A where A.DXID=B.DXID)
```

No need of `order by` clause

Above change is must.

You should once try `EXEC sys.sp_executesql` .

You should also try `Row_Number` once,with this you do not need second Select statement and no need of temp table.

Do not use "*".

Just try `With (Nolock)` hint: If it help then we discuss more about it.It is not always considered to be best practice, but try once.